# Help needed on resolving a string into MDX expression

Tags: ssas, mdx

The string is stored in a parameter.
Say, @FiscalPeriod = "[Date].[Fiscal Dates].[Fiscal Quarter]"

Now,
I need to use the parameter as

SELECT Measures.[Revenue] ON 0,
CLOSINGPERIOD("**Parameter Here**") ON 1
FROM [Sales]

STRTOMEBER function gives error because it is looking for a member at the leaf left such as
 [Date].[Fiscal Dates].[Fiscal Quarter].&[Q1 - 2009]

**How can I resolve the string into the mdx expression to use it with closing period??**

Comment: Was the question too trivial? or incomplete? or difficult to understand?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
SELECT Measures.[Revenue] ON 0,
STRTOMEMBER("CLOSINGPERIOD(" + @FiscalPeriod + ")") ON 1
FROM [Sales]
```